# Changing EditText on button click

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to change the text in an EditText widget when the user clicks on a button. For example: When button1 is pressed, "1" should be displayed in the EditText field but if button2 is pressed then "2" should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have an ID for your edittext field and have a onclick methods for your buttons. Then you can use `.setText()` on your edittext field in your java.

Your XML:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/yourId"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:onClick="button_1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:onClick="button_2"/>
```

Your Java:

```
public void button_1(View view) {
    //Button 1 is clicked
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourId)).setText("1");
}
public void button_2(View view) {
    //Button 2 is clicked
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourId)).setText("2");
}
```

This changes the text in the edittext field to respectivly 1 and 2 when button 1 or button 2 is clicked.